# Generate PNG with custom text from font file

Tags: script, fonts, png

I have ~200 font files and need to generate .png files that have text inside them rendered using the font in question.

Example:

```
Roboto.ttf (or any font format)

=> .png file that has text "Roboto"
```

I'm wondering if anyone is aware of a quick way to do this (i.e. not creating the png's manually in graphic design software).

Thank you.

Comment: An HTML Canvas with JavaScript could get you 80% of the way. The remaining 20% is how to save the image to a file.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks, that actually sounds like a great idea. Please add this as an answer. If nothing better comes along, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: This is available either at system level or by a font management app. It's built-in on Mac - eg https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QKFU.png …but you didn't tell us what OS you're on, or why you need to be digging in the fonts folders to try find a font by thumbnail. Hence, the XY Problem. You've found what you *think* is the answer to your issue, but you're asking about that, not how to solve your *actual* issue, which is how to see font previews.

Comment: You can use PrintMyFonts. I use it in such cases https://www.sttmedia.com/printmyfonts

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thanks. On quick look, this looks like it's more for previewing fonts with a fixed sentence for comparison, but I'll try it.

Comment: Tom, on the images you will have the name of the font :) So IMHO you do not need to enter it as sample text. Better check (in case of need) for nonlatin chars, ligatures, etc

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thank you. That sounds perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to use [PrintMyFonts](https://www.sttmedia.com/printmyfonts). This software offer great flexibility in sense of visualisation of font samples. You can show them on the screen, export to JPG, PNG, MS Word, RTF, html. Also you can preview fonts not installed in the OS. And of course you can select a lot of fonts and do the operation (review, export) over all of them. I test the software with >1000 fonts (not installed) and it work quite fast. This software can be run under Windows, Linux, MacOS.

P.S. No affiliation with the software author.